# Private RSA keys on a Tor hosting

Tags: onion-services, security, deanonymization

I'm wondering how Tor hosting providers handles using private RSA keys of their users so they can use their own .onion names.

As I understand, when I have a private RSA key and I send this private key to a Tor host and he runs it, I should be able somehow to get his real IP address using this RSA key, isn't that right?

I am not asking of how to do that, I am just asking 'How providers stay anonymous'. And how they can protect themselves.

Comment: If a provider hosts your hidden service for you, they have that hidden service's private keys. It's not clear why you think that you should be able to find out their public IP.

Answer (score 4):

> As I understand, when I have a private RSA key and I send this private key to a Tor host and he runs it, I should be able somehow to get his real IP address using this RSA key, isn't that right?

No.  The hidden service key is just used for signing stuff.  It won't let you decrypt any special information.

If the provider has the private key, it just means they owna the hidden service name just as much as you do.

Answer (score 0):

And take a look at new offline key options [here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13642)